# Show the next half hour time point in Postgres function

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I am trying to create a function that shows the next half hour time.

So when the current time is 13:40, I want it to show 14:00 and not 13:30.

What I have created, gets the job done but on the nearest half hour time, not the future nearest:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION round_timestamp(
         ts timestamptz
         ,round_secs int
        ) RETURNS timestamptz AS $$
        DECLARE
                _mystamp timestamp;
                _round_secs decimal;
        BEGIN
    _round_secs := round_secs::decimal;
    _mystamp := timestamptz 'epoch' 
            + ROUND((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts))::int / _round_secs) * _round_secs
            * INTERVAL '1 second';
    RETURN _mystamp;
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

Any ideas on how to make this work to display the future nearest half hour interval?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trivially, add 1 to the rounded down epoch before scaling it back up to a timestamp:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION round_timestamp(ts timestamptz, round_secs int)
    RETURNS timestamptz AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN timestamptz 'epoch' 
            + (ROUND((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts))::int / round_secs) + 1) * round_secs
            * INTERVAL '1 second';
END; $$ LANGUAGE plpgsql IMMUTABLE;
```

There is no need for the local variables.

Comment: if my current time is 15:25 does this function make it 15:30 ?

Comment: Run it in your server. If you specify 1800 for round_secs, then yes it will.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid tripping over on using epoch and floating point arithmetics, you can rely on date arithmetics, with the additional benefit of making it clearer what is going on:

```
create or replace function round_tstz(ts timestamptz)
  returns timestamptz
as $$
  select date_trunc('hour', $1) +
         -- what hour will it be in 30 min?
         case date_trunc('hour', $1 + interval '30 min')
         -- the same: round to next half hour
         when date_trunc('hour', $1) then interval '30 min'
         -- not the same: round to next hour
         else interval '1 hour'
         end;
$$ language sql stable;

# select now()::timestamptz(0);
          now           
------------------------
 2014-12-05 14:34:30+01
(1 row)

# select round_tstz(now()), round_tstz(now() + interval '30 min');
       round_tstz       |       round_tstz       
------------------------+------------------------
 2014-12-05 15:00:00+01 | 2014-12-05 15:30:00+01
(1 row)
```

Comment: I doubt that this approach would make much of a difference given that the timestamp itself is a double. It might even have worse performance because of all the logic that goes into `timestamp_trunc()` as compared to a simple epoch extraction and (often) hardware-optimized rounding.

Comment: @Patrick: Might be... I'd imagine that the logic in timestamp_trunc(), which is in C, and which would only get evaluated twice because the optimizer can skip one of the function calls because it's stable, fares a tiny bit faster than doing all of the floating point arithmetic resulting from not calling it (involving divisions and what not). At any rate, I don't think it matters much at the end of the day: what counts, I think, is that the approach I'm suggesting is many times more readable and comprehensible. But that's just my own opinion at the end of the day. :-)

Comment: Reading your example, this is only the beginning of your day... What are you doing on SO at 4:26am??? Working hours aside, all variants of timestamp_trunc() start out with a big case statement to evaluate the period of interest; `'hour'` in your example. In the problem of the OP it is better to get down to the second straightaway without any thinking on the part of PG.

Comment: @Patrick: Hehe. My laptop's server was misconfigured. :-D Anyway, I haven't checked the source code, so can only take your word for it. I still think it's better to write code as if the next guy will be a psychopath with an ax who knows where you live; as much as I try to be open to extracting epoch and such, I find that my own suggestion, or the one Kouper just posted, make what is going on more intuitive.

Comment: Yes, code clarity is important. One complication though: while the OP speaks of half hour intervals, his code example uses an arbitrary number of seconds to round up to. So if he wants 1864 seconds, then your code cannot round to 31 minutes and 4 seconds. But that is just a little anal on my part.

Comment: Hehe. The cynic in me has [an idea](http://www.rightbrainnetworks.com/blog/rounding-datetimes-and-timestamps-in-postgresql/) of why the unneeded parameter might have been there... ;-) Btw, did that `aclexplode()` solution I suggested you a few months ago end up working the way you hoped?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66268/discussion-between-patrick-and-denis).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ceil()` (or `ceiling()`) and `floor()`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html) to round up and down, respectively.

If your function is that simple, you can write it in `LANGUAGE SQL` too, which makes it more simple/readable (and plannable too by the parser):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION round_timestamp(ts timestamptz, round_secs int)
  RETURNS timestamptz
  LANGUAGE SQL
  IMMUTABLE
AS $func$
SELECT timestamptz 'epoch'
  + ceiling(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM ts) / round_secs)
  * round_secs
  * INTERVAL '1 second'
$func$;
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/c5715/2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `X` minutes to the current amount of minutes `M` in the timestamp, where:

**X** = 30 - **M** % 30 - 30 * ((**M** % 30)=0)::int

You subtract the remainder of the division to 30 from 30, and then only if that remainder is 0, subtract another 30, so that :00 and :30 values are kept and not rounded up as well.

For example, if the time is 14:11, then M = 11, you need to add 19 minutes to reach 14:30 (30 - 11 % 30 = 19), for 14:47, M = 47, you need to add 13 minutes to reach 15:00 (30 - 47 % 30 = 13). The only exception to that rule is the case when the remainder is 0, i.e. hours such as 14:30, 15:00, etc. - and that's where the last term in the formula comes into play - subtracting the product of 30 * (0 or 1, depending on the remainder of the division to 30).

```
CREATE FUNCTION round_up(timestamptz) RETURNS timestamptz AS $$
  SELECT
    $1 + '1 minute'::interval * (
      30 - (EXTRACT('minute' FROM $1)::int % 30)
         - 30 * ((EXTRACT('minute' FROM $1)::int % 30)=0)::int
    );
$$ LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE;
```

Comment: Since a `timestamp` has a micro-second resolution the issue of rounding up a "round" value is highly application-dependent and my guess would be that it is irrelevant.